# Email account has to been create

Tags: microsoft-account

My account is not complete.it is showing attention required.i want to create my new account use the phone..pls sort out my problem..
Microsoft lumia532 dual sim

Comment: Can you please breifly explain what is the problem you are facing? Did you get any error message? Can you post any screenshot without personal information?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create an email account but don't know how to go about it because the phone is getting stuck somewhere in the process. I suggest that you try and create an email account using a computer then later come login on your mobile using the email and password you generated. Creating an email account from the mobile phone can be annoyingly cumbersome at times